# Mysql self joining on max id returned from first table using groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join, laravel-query-builder

I need a sql that uses self join on max id from first table. Please look at the following image of table. I am grouping the table by service_id but I need the last message of each group. So For service group 5 message count should be 3 and last_message should be thirdMsg5. I wrote a sql below everything else is fine but it is throwing an error in the case of self join. It can't recognize `msgTbl1.last_message_id`. I think I am calling it before preparing it. I need help to solve this problem what would be the best sql to solve this in one query? And if possible please provide me this query in laravel query builder format.

```
SELECT count(msgTbl1.id) as message_count, 
       max(msgTbl1.id) as last_message_id, 
       msgTbl1.body, 
       msgTbl2.body as last_message, 
       services.name as service_name
FROM messages msgTbl1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, body FROM messages) AS msgTbl2 
   ON msgTbl2.id = msgTbl1.last_message_id
LEFT JOIN services on services.id = msgTbl1.service_id 
WHERE receiver_id = 4 AND read_user = 'no'
GROUP BY msgTbl1.service_id
```

[image]

sql for the message table

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sender_type` enum('user','agent','admin') NOT NULL,
  `receiver_type` enum('user','agent','admin') NOT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `files` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'serialize',
  `new_notification` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  `read_user` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `read_agent` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `status` enum('active','archive','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `service_id`, `sender_type`, `receiver_type`, `body`, `files`, `new_notification`, `read_user`, `read_agent`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 22, 4, 5, 'user', 'agent', 'firstMsg5', NULL, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'active', '2016-03-24 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 05:40:28'),
(2, 22, 4, 5, 'user', 'agent', 'secondMsg5', NULL, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'active', '2016-03-24 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 05:40:31'),
(3, 22, 4, 9, 'user', 'agent', 'firstMsg9', NULL, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'active', '2016-03-24 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 05:40:45'),
(4, 4, 4, 9, 'agent', 'user', 'secondMsg9', NULL, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'active', '2016-03-24 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 05:40:56'),
(5, 22, 4, 5, 'user', 'agent', 'thirdMsg5', NULL, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'active', '2016-03-24 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 05:41:08');
```

Comment: Thanks @rhavendc I tried it before, it doesn't work. same error.
**Unknown column 'last_message_id' in 'on clause'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT message_count, 
       last_message_id, 
       msgTbl1.body,        
       services.name as service_name
FROM messages msgTbl1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) AS last_message_id, COUNT(*) AS message_count
   FROM messages
   WHERE read_user = 'no'
   GROUP BY service_id) AS msgTbl2 
   ON msgTbl1.id = msgTbl2.last_message_id
LEFT JOIN services on services.id = msgTbl1.service_id 
WHERE receiver_id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos for your reply.
But it doesn't solve yet
https://gyazo.com/f2d21a638fd0b4b4bb2e2c95fb14bd11
It is showing some two messages under same service.
look firstMsg5 and secondMsg5 are in same service.
I need output like it
https://gyazo.com/163e76c86185228642a92c95cbb3dfcd

Comment: @murad Try with `INNER JOIN` and tell me what results you get.

Comment: INNER JOIN throwing an empty result.

Comment: @murad This is not possible. Can you provide the sample data you are using to produce the result set of the OP?

Comment: Sure I can send the table to you, may I send it to you?

Comment: @murad Can you edit your question and add sample data as formatted text?

Comment: Please check the question if it helps.

Comment: @murad The reason you get no result is because in the last message has `read_user  = yes`. Do you want last message with `read_user = 'no'`?

Comment: Thank you. close enough. But if the read_user for last one is yes then it should consider the others at same service group which read_user status is no.
It is ignoring the service group if the last message's read_user is yes.
It should take if anyone is unread.

Comment: @murad You didn't describe this requirement in your post. How can somebody answer if this requirement is missing?

Comment: I am really sorry for misunderstanding. My given query set condition on first table not the second. If we set where condition on first table we don't have to think about if last one is read or unread it will take if it get any unread message within that condition. 
I think it is my fault not to describe more precisely sorry again. Can you please help me with this requirement?

Comment: @murad Please check the edit I made. Does this meet your requirement?